# Is it possible to "simplify" a MultiPolygon?

Tags: python, shapely

See the following example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Point

# (1) Is valid

hulls = [[(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10)],
         [(10.000001, 5), (20, 5), (20, 10), (10.000001, 10)]]  #

area = MultiPolygon([(hulls[0], []),
                     (hulls[1], [])])

print(area.is_valid)
print(area.contains(Point(5, 5)))

# (2) Crashes

hulls = [[(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10)],
         [(5, 5), (20, 5), (20, 10), (5, 10)]]

area = MultiPolygon([(hulls[0], []),
                     (hulls[1], [])])
print(area.is_valid)
print(area.contains(Point(5, 5)))
```

The reason why (2) crashes and (1) works is because the multiple polygons in (1) are completely exclusive; they don't overlap at all. In (2), they overlap.

I don't really care about the underlying representation. Is it possible to make a MultiPolygon valid automatically in such cases?

### What I found

```
simplify(self, tolerance, preserve_topology=True)
 |      Returns a simplified geometry produced by the Douglas-Peucker
 |      algorithm
```

This is not working. I want to get exactly the same result for contains... just without overlapping polygons.

Answer (score 0):

A simple working solution is:

```
def is_point_in_multipolygon(point, multi):
    for polygon in multi:
        if polygon.contains(point):
            return True
    return False
```

It is not so nice because it might be more computationally intensive than necessary, but likely for most cases that doesn't matter.